# Get elements with active class and send them in Ajax with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

If I have this HTML:

```
<form>
    <a href="#" data-name="color" data-value="yellow" class="active">
    <a href="#" data-name="color" data-value="red">
    <a href="#" data-name="color" data-value="orange">

    <a href="#" data-name="fruit" data-value="banana" class="active">
    <a href="#" data-name="fruit" data-value="apple">

    <buton id="send">Send</button>
</form>
```

How can I create an array with all the `<a class="active">` through Ajax to play with them in PHP after ?

Thanks.

Comment: do you want to send the actual element or their data value to the `PHP` - i do think there is a point sending an actual element to PHP ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping yes, I would like to pass these values to PHP.

Comment: Added my answer below of using ajax and sending data - which you really needed instead of what you selected as answer - There is no point creating an array and then loop again in that array to send data to PHP - you can simplify it just by using formData - Let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [formData](https://www.google.com/search?q=formData&rlz=1C1CHZL_enAU805AU805&oq=formData&aqs=chrome..69i57.207j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to send the `value` and `name` data attribute of element having `active` class to your `PHP` back end file.

There is `NO` point creating an `array` and looping through that `array` again to send / create `formData` for ajax. That is totally unnecessary.

Please note: You can **NOT** send an `array` in an `ajax` request. So your probably need this solution as per your question.

Initialize `formData` and append your `name` and `value` attribute to it in a `$.each` and then send that `formData` using `ajax`

**Working Demo:**

```js
//Initilize formData
var formData = new FormData()

//Each through elements
$('a').each(function(index, element) {
  //check all element with class active only
  if ($(element).attr('class') == 'active') {
    //append active class data-name and value
    formData.append($(element).data('name'), $(element).data('value'))
  }
})

//Click event
$('#send').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  // Display the key/value pairs of formData - demo only
  for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
  }

  //call ajax on send button click
  $.ajax({
    url: 'some_url.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <a href="#" data-name="color" data-value="yellow" class="active">
  </a>
  <a href="#" data-name="color" data-value="red">
  </a>
  <a href="#" data-name="color" data-value="orange">
  </a>

  <a href="#" data-name="fruit" data-value="banana" class="active"></a>
  <a href="#" data-name="fruit" data-value="apple">
  </a>

  <button id="send">Send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create normal array and then using ***each*** loop add value to that array or you can create ***JSON Array*** and push value like key-value pair using same each loop.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var arr = [] //create arry

$("form > a.active").each(function() {
  arr.push($(this).attr('data-value')) //push value in array
})
console.log(arr)

var json_array = [];
$("form > a.active").each(function() {
  item = {}; //object create
  item[$(this).attr('data-name')] = $(this).attr('data-value')
  json_array.push(item) //push value in array
});

console.log(json_array)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <a href="#" data-name="color" data-value="yellow" class="active"> </a>
  <a href="#" data-name="color" data-value="red"> </a>
  <a href="#" data-name="color" data-value="orange"> </a>

  <a href="#" data-name="fruit" data-value="banana" class="active"> </a>
  <a href="#" data-name="fruit" data-value="apple">
  </a>
  <button id="send">Send</button>
</form>
```