# Send an JS array through Ajax

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I've this type of array in JS:

```js
[{
  websitetype: "onepager"
}, {
  layout: "provided"
}, {
  layout_provided: "wireframes"
}, {
  languages: "single"
}, {
  client_name: "dasda"
}, {
  client_email: "asdasd@asdasd.fr"
}, {
  client_conditions: "on"
}, {
  client_newsletter: "on"
}]
```

How can I send it through Ajax ?

---

What I tried is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'assets/send.php',
    data: {datas},
    success: function(response) { },
});
```

---

This is what I would like to get in PHP:

```
[datas] => Array
    (
        [websitetype] => onepager
        [layout] => provided
        [layout_provided] => wireframes
        [languages] => single
        [client_name] => dasda
        [client_email] => asdasd@asdasd.fr
        [client_conditions] => on
        [client_newsletter] => on
    )
```

What I'm missing here please ?

Thanks.

Comment: This entirely depends on what your `send.php` script expects

Comment: Is `datas` defined?  Does it contain the data you're expecting?  In your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, is the data present on the request?  How specifically does this fail?

Comment: @Phil, code updated with the desired output in PHP. Actually I have an array in an array.

Comment: You can not send a whole array like that via ajax. thats what i said in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64088350/13669048) here - use formData object to send all the HTML data whatever you have to make it easy for you. **Looking at the questions you are posting** they all come to one thing which is sending data to PHP - it can be simplified uisng formData. there is NO point storing data in an ARRAY (unless it being used somewhere else too) and then looping that array to send data in a formData and to send to PHP. hope this makes all sense. :)

Comment: @AlwaysHelping _"You can not send a whole array like that via ajax"_. Sure you can. That's what the `application/json` content-type is for

Comment: @Phil Yes!!! but simple array No you can NOT - like this `JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(datas.flatMap(o => Object.entries(o)))),` offcourse Phil - formData is way much simpler looking what OP is trying to achieve that what i suggested only.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping sorry mate, not following you there

Comment: @Phil for example : `let datas = [{foo; {bar}; {blah}]` and the in ajax `data:datas` = would that work - simply like that ? the formData will become [Object Object] correct.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping jQuery's [`$.param()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) serialiser can do some impressive things but in OP's case, I would stick to sending raw JSON rather than trying to massage the data into something usable in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: @Phil Yes i agree. the solution you suggested will work in OP's case. Nice one :) But i still give `formData` a preference to make things simpler just only because looking at OP's question which were posted a few recently and yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you should do is reduce that *array* into an object matching the format you want

```
const dataObject = Object.fromEntries(datas.flatMap(o => Object.entries(o)))
```

This looks like the following

```js
{
  "websitetype": "onepager",
  "layout": "provided",
  "layout_provided": "wireframes",
  "languages": "single",
  "client_name": "dasda",
  "client_email": "asdasd@asdasd.fr",
  "client_conditions": "on",
  "client_newsletter": "on"
}
```

You then have two options for posting it to PHP

1. Send it as raw JSON

   ```js
   $.ajax({
     method: "POST",
     url: "assets/send.php",
     contentType: "application/json",
     data: JSON.stringify(dataObject),
     processData: false
   })
   ```

   Then read and parse the JSON in PHP

   ```php
   $datas = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

   // example
   echo $datas["websitetype"]; // "onepager"
   ```
2. Alternatively, let jQuery format the data as an associative PHP array

   ```js
   $.ajax({
     method: "POST",
     url: "assets/send.php",
     data: {
       datas: dataObject
     }
   })
   ```

   This will post an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request body of

   ```
   datas%5Bwebsitetype%5D=onepager&datas%5Blayout%5D=provided&datas%5Blayout_provided%5D=wireframes&datas%5Blanguages%5D=single&datas%5Bclient_name%5D=dasda&datas%5Bclient_email%5D=asdasd%40asdasd.fr&datas%5Bclient_conditions%5D=on&datas%5Bclient_newsletter%5D=on
   ```

   PHP can read this as an array via `$_POST`

   ```php
   print_r($_POST['datas']);
   ```

   Results in

   ```
   Array
   (
       [websitetype] => onepager
       [layout] => provided
       [layout_provided] => wireframes
       [languages] => single
       [client_name] => dasda
       [client_email] => asdasd@asdasd.fr
       [client_conditions] => on
       [client_newsletter] => on
   )
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Encode your data string into JSON.

```
const datas = [{
  websitetype: "onepager"
}, {
  layout: "provided"
}, {
  layout_provided: "wireframes"
}, {
  languages: "single"
}, {
  client_name: "dasda"
}, {
  client_email: "asdasd@asdasd.fr"
}, {
  client_conditions: "on"
}, {
  client_newsletter: "on"
}]
const jsonString = JSON.stringify(datas)

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'assets/send.php',
    data: { datas: jsonString },
    success: function(response) { },
});
```

In your PHP:

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['datas']));

// here i would like use foreach:

foreach($datas as $data){
   echo $data;
}
```

Comment: Why send JSON over `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?